# How do i get rid of the degree sign from my integer when i want to convert it from a string in a dictionary?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, type-conversion, integer

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
Measurments = {'Kitchen': '22°', 'Master bedroom': '19°', 'Sitting room': '21°', 'Toilet': '24°', 'Guest bedroom': '18°', 'Garage': '15°', 'Outside': '12°'}

and want to save it in a new dictionary as follows:
```

newDictionary = {'Kitchen': 22, 'Master bedroom': 19, 'Sitting room': 21, 'Toilet': 24, 'Guest bedroom': 18, 'Garage': 15, 'Outside': 12}

```
i have tried :
```

```
newDictionary = {str(k):int(v) for k,v in measurements.items()}
```

but it gave me this error code:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '22°'
```

How do i get rid of the degree sign so i can get the values as integers?

Comment: There are many solutions that you can use depending on the values you get as shown in answers.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
newDictionary = {key:int(value.replace('°', '')) for key,value in Measurments.items()}
```

since your values are all strings now, you can use replace method to remove the °, and then it will be able to convert it to int

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follow by removing the unwanted character before converting it to `int`

```py
newDictionary = {str(k):int(v[:-1]) for k,v in measurements.items()}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure if everything has a degree, you can simply do as below.

```py
measurements = {'Kitchen': '22°', 'Master bedroom': '19°', 'Sitting room': '21°', 'Toilet': '24°', 'Guest bedroom': '18°', 'Garage': '15°', 'Outside': '12°'}

newDictionary = {str(k):int(v[:-1]) for k,v in measurements.items()}

print(newDictionary)
```